# Loop in a callback returned array using Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

i'm trying to achieve something like this :

```
describe("TEST",function() {

    Offer.find({},{_id:1, title:1}).exec(function(error, offers) {

        for (var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {
    it("Ask transaction : " + offers[i].title, function(done) {
            // do something with offers[i];
    }
}
...
```

But Mocha does not even detect a test in the file. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every test case starts with the `it("", function(){ /* write test code here */ } )` code block.

If you are looking at performing some test setup like inserting data then you can use the `before` function to do those.

**Example:**

```
describe("TEST",function() {
   before(function() {
       // runs before all tests in this block
   });
   it("should blah", function(done) {
       // Your test case starts here.
   }
}
```

There are examples in Mocha's official site you can refer to;

**See:**
https://mochajs.org/

Comment: Thanks ! this before() function was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So, thanks to your answer and some research i managed to do exactly what i wanted.

```
describe("TRANSACTIONS TESTS",function() {

var offers;

before(function(done) {
    Offer.find({},{_id:1, title:1}).exec(function(error, result) {
        offers = result;
        done();
    });
});


it("TEST ALL OFFERS", function(done) {

    for (var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {

        const tmp_i = i;

        server
            .post('/transactions')
            .send(data)
            .expect("Content-type",/json/)
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err,res) {

                 // DO TEST STUFF HERE

                if (tmp_i == offers.length - 1) {
                    done();
                }
            });

    }
});
```

The const variable is necessary to avoid an error (i being always equals to the maximum size of the array instead of incrementing)